# How to use grep to get a tag value

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a file (say file.txt) containing data like below

```
^A15=0^A18=20170924065847986457^A21=0^A22=2
```

How can I use grep to get the value of tag 18?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1):

As requested with (gnu) grep:

```
echo "^A15=0^A18=20170924065847986457^A21=0^A22=2" | grep -oP "A18=\K\d+"
```

output:

`20170924065847986457`

The \K is the short and efficient form of (?<=pattern) which you use as a zero-width look-behind assertion before the text you want to output.

Answer (score 0):

This is not suited for `grep`, which is meant for filtering rather than extraction.

You can use `perl` instead:

```
perl -pe 's/.*\^A18=([^^]+).*/$1/' <<< '^A15=0^A18=20170924065847986457^A21=0^A22=2'
```

This outputs: `20170924065847986457`